# I inserted the json file into my table, but how do i put in the date into my table as well?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

Here is how my table is turning out. All I have left to do is insert the current
date in the dateloaded:

[image]

I've been trying to add a date when the data from the JSON file is loaded into the table but don't know the correct syntax. Any help please? :)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Sql server 2017

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from your comment below another answer:

> That didn't quite work this was the error "Column name or number of
>   supplied values does not match table definition."

The issue you have is related to

```
insert into main.jsontable
select * from...
```

You should never rely on the columns order. The columns you are inserting to and the columns you are reading from must match. The worst case is a wrong match by coincidence.

About [bad habits to kick: `SELECT` with `*`](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)

Change this to

```
insert into main.jsontable(name, surname, email, ...more columns...)
select <list your JSON "columns" here> 
from...
```

The final step then is to include the `dateloaded` to this:

```
insert into main.jsontable(dateloaded, name, surname, email, ...more columns...)
select SYSUTCDATETIME(), <list your JSON "columns" here> 
from...
```

### UPDATE

You were told already, that posting pictures is something to avoid. It's hard to read from there, but it seems you are trying to solve this here

```
with(
[dateloaded] datetimeoffset,
[name] ...
```

This *derived column* will never get any value as you are not reading this out of your JSON.

Comment: Oh my IT WORKED! Thank you i have been looking for hours

Answer (score 0):

You can use GETDATE(), is actual datetime.

Answer (score 0):

`sysdatetimeofffset()` should do what you want. Line up the columns, and something like the following should work:

```
select *, sysdatetimeoffset() from
openjson(@PersonDetails, <etc>
```

Comment: This will include UTC, which I think you specified in your pre-edited post.

Comment: That didn't quite work this was the error "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition."